# Android: After relese an APK (in release mode), when i open camera model in an application. App will crash?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediaplayer, release

Android: After relese an APK (in release mode), when i open camera model in an application. App will crashed.
But in dubbug mode it works perfectly(in dubbug mode)

**Find Logcat msg:**

```
08-17 15:04:54.600 6202-6290/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: MediaPlayerThread
                                                 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: veg.mediaplayer.sdk.MediaPlayer.ˊ:([JLveg/mediaplayer/sdk/MediaPlayer;)J
                                                     at veg.mediaplayer.sdk.MediaPlayer.ˊ(Native Method)
                                                     at o.gr.run(:3969)
                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Note: Dependent Lib :"MediaPlayer" added in gradle as well in libs folder of the project.

**As per me, "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found:" says that requried library is not found but same configuration works fine in debbug mode.**

Please any one help me to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is 3rd party library related issue, Check with library settings. Delete your "lib" folder and paste it again... and than Clean project, Rebuild project and Run the App. I faced same problem last project so i did the same.
Its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution for above issue, This is completly related to DexGard,

Crashing Reason: because of DexGard not allows the library jar file when the app is in release mode.

Thanks.,

Answer (score 0):

Its App/project Setting issue... check with ur project setting